# Add property to existing VBA class

Tags: class, excel, vba

I would like to do something like add a nice-to-Excel-functions `Name` property to the `WorkBook` class. Is there a good way to do this?

More detailed problem: In VBA you can assign a formula to a range in an Excel worksheet. I want to do so, and I want my formula to refer to a second workbook, which is an object called `wb` in my code. I then use `wb.Name` in assigning a formula to a range.

The problem arises when `wb.Name` has a single-quote in it. Then you wind up with something like this:

```
=MONTH('[Ryan's WB]Sheet1'A1)
```

in the spreadsheet, which fails because the single-quote in the workbook name matches to the first single-quote.

What I would like is a `FunName` property for the `WorkBook` class that replaces all single-quotes in the `Name` property with two single-quotes and returns that. Then the above formula would properly wind up looking like

```
=MONTH('[Ryan''s WB]Sheet1'A1)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You don't need to make a separate class to extend the workbook class.  You can add properties to the existing ThisWorkbook class module, like this:

```
Public Property Get FunName() As String

    FunName = Replace(Me.Name, "'", "''")

End Property
```

Then you call `ThisWorkbook.FunName` to get your cleaned up name.  However, this code has to exist in the workbook at hand.  If you want it to work on *any* workbook, your function is the way to go.

Answer (score 1):

Just do a replace to double up the single quotes

```
WorksheetName = Replace(WB.Name, "'", "''")
```

Answer (score 1):

What you need is a Class which extends the Workbook object. Insert a class module, then try the following code

```
Dim WithEvents WB As Workbook

Public Sub SetWB(W As Workbook)
  Set WB = W
End Sub

Public Property Get FunName() As String
  FunName = Replace(WB.Name, "'", "''")
End Property

Private Sub WB_SheetCalculate(ByVal Sh As Object)
  'this runs when WB calculates
End Sub
```

'use it like this

```
Dim WB As New wbClass
WB.SetWB ActiveWorkbook
CleanedName = WB.FunName
```

Note that as a bonus, I've put WithEvents in the line that Dims WB at the top of the class. This allows you to trap all the events that happen to WB, and I included the Calculate event as a demo above. If you are in the class code and click the objects dropdown at top left of the code pane, you'll see the WB object, and if you click this, the right hand list box will give you all the events to choose from.

Comment: Absolutely perfect! This is exactly what I was looking for. Thank you!

Comment: OK, nearly perfect. It appears now that wbClass objects only have access to the FunName property. Is there some way to retain the entirety of the original WB object and add the FunName property?

Comment: Unfortunately not, VBA doesn't support inheritance, you have to replicate anything you want. (Personally, I would just add a normal Function to do this, rather than extending objects).

Answer (score 1):

The final answer appears to be that the WorkBook class can be extended to include a name property that is nice to Excel formulas. This can be done using the method provided by dbb. However, since VBA does not support inheritance, objects of the extended class will have only the properties you define for them.

Therefore, it really makes more sense to just use a function. Here's what I'm going to use:

```
Function FormulaWorkName(ByVal aName As String) As String
    FormulaWorkName = Replace(aName, "'", "''")
End Function
```

Which I will apply to both worksheet names and workbook names.